# Can I undo overwritten files?

Tags: blend-files

I accidentally overwrote a blend file. I was making a small thing and instead of opening something else I saved new small unimportant file over one of my biggest projects. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I already know the awnser! You just go to files to open one. Then by the filters you check the one next to the blender logo. then you click the .blend1 version of your file. save it as the file how it was before and you're done!